# Angular Material 2 customisation

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How input date display format can be changed to "dd MMM yy"? Also how start day of week in displayed calendar of date picker can be set to Monday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5722)

You will need to extend NativeDateAdapter and override **format** and **getFirstDayOfWeek** methods

Then add to providers

```
{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MyDateAdapter},
```

Comment: There is an issue, it display selected date correctly but it doesn't read from input the same way. It display in dd/mm/yyyy format but reads in mm/dd/yyyy format!. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @mehran look to parse method :)

Comment: @mehran https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/datetime/native-date-adapter.ts here is sources of method